# Adding custom propery to a JTree node

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I need to store some data in a `JTree` node. Is it possible to add a custom property to a node to hold my data?

Comment: hmm ... what's wrong with setUserData(..)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a node class that extends say DefaultMutableTreeNode with a property for your data.

```
public final class MyDataNode extends DefaultMutableTreeNode {
    private final MyData myData;

    public MyDataNode(MyData myData) {
        this.myData = myData;
    }

    public MyData getMyData() {
        return myData;
    }
}
```